# R Function Not Returning as Expected

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been working on a function in R, and looking to return a data.frame.  However, when I run, it return 0 rows/0 columns.  I did add a "print" in the if statement, and that works, so I know it's performing as intended within the loop and if statement.

Here is the function:

```
predict.next.word <- function(word, ng_matrix){
if(ncol(ng_matrix)==3){
    for (i in 1:100){
        ngram_df <- data.frame()
        first_word <- ng_matrix[,1][i]
        second_word <- ng_matrix[,2][i]
        count_word <- ng_matrix[,3][i]
        if (word[1] == first_word && !is.na(first_word)){
            matched_factor <- structure(c(second_word, count_word), .Names = c("predicted", "count"))
            matched_df <- as.data.frame(as.list(matched_factor))
            ngram_df <- (rbind(ngram_df, matched_df))
            ngram_df <- transform(ngram_df, count = as.numeric(count))
            print (ngram_df) # this works great, but not intention of function 
            }
        }  
    return (ngram_df)    
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of when I call it:

```
test_bigram_word <- c("a")
predict.next.word(test_bigram_word, bigram_index)
```

Comment: At the minimum, `first_word <- ng_matrix[,1][i]` needs to be `first_word <- ng_matrix[i,1]` and the same for the next 2 lines.

Comment: you're overwritting `ngram_df` on each iteration

Comment: Is `ng_matrix` guaranteed to have 100 rows always?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by moving the initializing of the dataframe above the for loop, like this:

```
predict.next.word <- function(word, ng_matrix){
if(ncol(ng_matrix)==3){
   ngram_df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:100){
    first_word <- ng_matrix[,1][i]
    second_word <- ng_matrix[,2][i]
    count_word <- ng_matrix[,3][i]
    if (word[1] == first_word && !is.na(first_word)){
        matched_factor <- structure(c(second_word, count_word), .Names = c("predicted", "count"))
        matched_df <- as.data.frame(as.list(matched_factor))
        ngram_df <- (rbind(ngram_df, matched_df))
        ngram_df <- transform(ngram_df, count = as.numeric(count))
        print (ngram_df) # this works great, but not intention of function 
        }
    }  
return (ngram_df)    
}
}
```